# Android - Compound View with separate horizontal/vertical layouts (independent from screen orientation)

Tags: android, android-layout

I was recently tasked with creating a compound view element as an exercise. I found this to be a relatively simple task, however I am somewhat stumped by the following requirement:

**- The component has to have both a horizontal and a vertical layout (selected via an attribute).**

The compound view is (effectively) a single `LinearLayout` with one `EditText` and two `Button` elements, one before it and one after. This would make solving the task trivial (just letting the user change the `android:orientation` attribute it inherited from `LinearLayout`), if it weren't for two factors:

1. In the horizontal version, I want the top `Button` to be on the **right** of the `EditText` instead of the left (so effectively make the layout right-to-left as far as element order in the horizontal orientation is concerned).
2. Depending on the layout, the components should have different width and height values (for instance, `Button` width set to `match_parent` in vertical layout, but `wrap_content` in horizontal).

It seems like it would be most easily solved with two separate layout files (one for each orientation), but I can't seem to be able to find any information on how to achieve that - which is leading me to the conclusion that it might be impossible. If so, what would be the easiest way to achieve that goal?

**Just to reiterate, I don't mean different layouts depending on screen orientation - the layouts have to be selectable while adding the component into the application.**

Comment: are you aware of `LayoutInflater`?

Comment: ...hmm...I COULD probably use it to inflate a different layout depending on the set attribute...I'll try that.

Comment: Seems like changing which layout file is passed to the `LayoutInflater` is the way to go, however now I can't seem to figure out how to check if `android:orientation` is set to `horizontal` or `vertical`...gotta look more stuff up, I guess.

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)